# how to pass url parameter in rest client

Tags: c#, wcf-rest, rest-client

I have two method like in interface

```
   [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/InsertDetails/{FirstName}/{CustomerName}/{LastName}/{Address}",
         Method = "PUT",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    void InsertDetails(string FirstName, string CustomerName, string LastName, string Address);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
          UriTemplate = "/Insert/",Method="PUT")]
    void InsertDetailsData(CustomerClass custmer);
```

and I want test these methods in restclient plugin ...
How do I pass Parameter in InsertDetails method.

Comment: You can create a JSON which represents your `CustomerClass` and add it to the request body.

Comment: sorry bt i didnt get u.....plz describe clearly

Answer (score 0):

If you setup a json endpoint you can use your browser to test your methods.
I assume you have a basicHttpBinding and want another (rest/json) endpoint:

Service side:
in services.service section:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" cotract="YourLibrary.YourService"/>   
<endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding"  contract="YourLibrary.YourService" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior" />
```

in behaviors section:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
        <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

You can now use your browser to access your service: just append to your base address /json/InsertDetails/param1/param2/param3/param4

You can access the service from your apps by setting up the client something like this:

```
 <client>
      <endpoint address="your base address/json"
        binding="webHttpBinding"  contract="YourLibrary.YourService" name="webHttpBinding_IMilewatchService" />
    </client>
```

You can as well invoke the service manually (open an url with WebClient class)

Answer (score 0):

If your URL is http://somedomain.com, then you would do like:

```
http://somedomain.com/InsertDetails/Homer/The%20Simpsons/Simpson/123%20Street%20St
```

Comment: actually I am talking about restClient plugin of chrome.In that plugin how do I pass my param values

Comment: Like that. In the URL.